# How to check, which hierarchy is being used

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have 1 dimension Data with 2 hierarchies: Gregorian Calendar, Planning Calendar.
[Gregorian Year] - [Gregorian Month] - [Gregorian Day]
[Planning Year] - [Planning Month] - [Planning Day]
I have 2 MDX measures:

```
[Planning Stock] = Sum(PeriodsToDate([Data].[Planning Calendar].[(All)]), [amount])

[Gregorian Stock] = Sum(PeriodsToDate([Data].[Gregorian Calendar].[(All)]), [amount])
```

How to create one measure that will recognize the hierarchy?
I wrote something like that, but it does not work :(

```
iif(([Data].currentmember.level is [Data].[Planning Calendar].[(All)]),
(Sum(PeriodsToDate([Data].[Planning Calendar].[(All)]), [amount])),
(Sum(PeriodsToDate([Data].[Gregorian Calendar].[(All)]), [amount]))
)
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the level.hierarchy. Take a look at the example.

```
with member 
measures.t
as 
axis(1).item(0).hierarchy.name

select 
{
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],measures.t
}
on columns,
{
[Date].[Fiscal].[Month].&[2014]&[7].children
--[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2013]&[6].children
}
on rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

Result

[image]

Lets change the hierarchy

```
with member 
measures.t
as 
axis(1).item(0).hierarchy.name

select 
{
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],measures.t
}
on columns,
{
--[Date].[Fiscal].[Month].&[2014]&[7].children
[Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2013]&[6].children
}
on rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

Result

[image]